# xcode xml web service missing node

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, web-services

Although the proper operation of the Web service or Web service xcode comes with missing content. There are five nodes in the web service node values ​​are, however, two of reply from the web service does not.How can I solve this problem?

```
<parent>
   <node1> content1 </node1>
   <node2> content2 </node2>
   <node3> longer content  </node3>// missing response
</parent>
```